# Need help identifying spider

Tags: species-identification, arachnology

I have been trying to identity this spider and have found nothing similar. This is the second I have found, this being the smaller at about 2cm. I want to know what kind of spider this is and if it is potentially dangerous to myself or my pets. June 2021, NW Turkey, fourth floor balcony. Thank you
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: A picture of the eye pattern might help with ID.

Comment: Looks to me like one of the Laceweavers: Amaurobius or something along those lines.  They rend to be fairly plain, powerful-looking ground-hunting spiders, and often have a dark reddish-brown carapace, with a dark, weakly patterned abdomen.  From what I can see of the eyes, they're consistent with that..  Unfortunately, the spider has been dead long enough to leave me uncertain, especially because my knowledge of European spiders is a bit limited.  It's definitely not a Mygalomorph tarantula, though.  No matter what, it's not one of the problem biters.

Comment: I agree with @JohnRobinson that Amauribidae is a good possibility, that it is Entelegyne (not Mygalomorph), and that its current (dried-up) state makes it hard to be sure of Family.

Answer (score -2):

The spider looks very similar to *Tarantulas*. They are not harmful to humans but can show allergic reactions in pets when bitten by a spider.

Check out this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarantula.

Comment: _"They are not harmful to humans but can show allergic reactions in pets when bitten by a spider."_ Actually not only to pets and when bitten - their hairs, especially on the legs, can cause respiratory and dermatologic irritations to humans and pets..

Comment: This is not a tarantula or even in the Mygalomorph infraorder.

Comment: You are more likely to get a positive response to your answer if you explain why your identification is correct. Specifically, please [edit] your answer to add discussion of key features that led you to this conclusion and supporting references or at least validated images. Without this your answer is indistinguishable from opinion, which is not appropriate for this site. Please consult the [help] starting with [answer] for details of what is expected.